# Weird ordering behavior in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run the below query in the **postgresql**

```
SELECT module
FROM(
    VALUES ('Data Archiving/Back-Up/Recovery'), ('Database Management Software'), ('Data Warehousing/Mining')
) s(module) ORDER BY module ASC;
```

I'm expecting the order should look like below

| module |
| --- |
| Data Archiving/Back-Up/Recovery |
| Data Warehousing/Mining |
| Database Management Software |

But it shows in below order

| module |
| --- |
| Data Archiving/Back-Up/Recovery |
| Database Management Software |
| Data Warehousing/Mining |

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: You don't say why you think the given order is wrong. Are you familiar with how "collation" works and can be changed? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/collation.html

Comment: `...ORDER BY module collate "C" ASC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you should realy check the PostgreSQL [COLLATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/collation.html) support (a search with "postgresql weird order" quickly directs you toward)

**Example**

```
select * from (values
('Data Warehouse'),
('Data Archive'),
('Database')
) t(txt)
order by 1

txt           |
--------------+
Data Archive  |
Database      |
Data Warehouse|


select * from (values
('Data Warehouse'),
('Data Archive'),
('Database')
) t(txt)
order by txt collate "C";

txt           |
--------------+
Data Archive  |
Data Warehouse|
Database      |
```